# Как (чем) открыть *.pak файл Sony Ericsson

Tags: разработка-игр, мобильная-разработка, обратная-разработка

Как (чем/какой программой) открыть *.pak-файл с ресурсами (ассетами) видеоигры написанной для телефона Sony Ericsson? (Подразумевается, что всё лежит на ПК и открывать тоже нужно на ПК).

Проблема состоит в том, что:

1. Существует несколько форматов файлов с общим названием: *.pak
2. Есть подозрение (гипотеза), что подлинный формат файла - самопальный - авторов оригинальной игры (игра старая и, вроде даже компании её создавшей больше нет => вариант "связаться с разработчиками и спросить" отпадает), а расширение *.pak используется только потому, что это упакованные данные. Точно известно лишь то, что расширение файлов - *.pak (повторюсь, про самодельность формата - моя гипотеза, основанная на том, что пока открыть ни один файл мне не удалось), а содержимое файлов - текстуры, тексты и аудио, вероятно сжатые. Однако это всё, что точно известно.

Контекст задачи в том, чтобы попытаться (в исследовательских целях) портировать одну игру с вышеприведённого кнопочного телефона на Android. Если декомпилировать исходники *.jar файла удалось (с получением java-подобной тарабарщины), то с доступом к игровым ресурсам (текстуры спрайтов, шрифты и т.п.) всё упёрлось в проблему открытия *.pak-файлов, располагавшихся в том же *.jar файле, что и откомпилированные *.class файлы.

Структура файла такая:

Container/game.class
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
res/<файлы с расширением *.pak - о которых речь>
.timestamp
<несколько файлов *.class>
icon.png

На крайний случай, рассматриваю также такой вариант: т.к. игра как-то все эти данные извлекала из этих файлов, то, возможно есть какой-то способ извлечь ресурсы программно. Но для этого нужно знать чем (напр. какой библиотекой) их можно вычитать из этих *.pak файлов. К сожалению, чем они подгружаются я понять не смог: ни явной загрузки (вызовов типа Load/Read/Open чего-нибудь подобное), ни ссылок на используемые ресурсы (что-нибудь Resource = строка/число/ключ) я не нашёл (видимо не так искал или не то: в конце концов на Sony Ericsson игр я раньше не писал).

Но главный вопрос - прежний: как открыть *.pak файл?

[Upd: 17.12.21] Успел попробовать Game Extractor, не помогло, скрин ниже:
[image]

На всякий случай, выкладываю ссылку на архив папки res - возможно кому-либо удастся открыть какой-нибудь из этих *.pak файлов. Ссылка на архив - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Esj5GXKEglc8wCE54pKHrChxREfXmJd0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: [Посмотрите](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/c4aj6a/how_to_extract_pak_files/), может, найдёте что полезное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После множественных провальных попыток открыть файлы с ресурсами игры (различными программами) и досконального изучения декомпилированных исходников старой игры, выяснил, что мои худшие опасения (см. цитату ниже) оправдались: расширение *.pak лишь вводило в заблуждение, а сами данные считывались программно, по байтовым оффсетам в файлах (алгоритмом самой видеоигры) - т.е. файл - просто набор оффсетов и последовательно (побайтово) расположенных данных (картинки, звуки и др. ресурсы игры).

> Есть подозрение (гипотеза), что подлинный формат файла - самопальный -
> авторов оригинальной игры (игра старая и, вроде даже компании её
> создавшей больше нет => вариант "связаться с разработчиками и
> спросить" отпадает), а расширение *.pak используется только потому,
> что это упакованные данные. Точно известно лишь то, что расширение
> файлов - *.pak (повторюсь, про самодельность формата - моя гипотеза,
> основанная на том, что пока открыть ни один файл мне не удалось), а
> содержимое файлов - текстуры, тексты и аудио, вероятно сжатые. Однако
> это всё, что точно известно.

Answer (score 1):

Вам потребуется [Game Extractor](http://www.watto.org/extract/).

Прочтите также http://wiki.xentax.com/index.php/Time_Splitters_Future_Perfect_PAK

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Но, в моём случае, Game Extractor, к сожалению, не помог.